# Delphi Need to take Data from a Web page

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I need to take this football data from this page. When i use idhttp.get the data not included in source code.
Please help.

The webpage i need the data is this
http://praktoreio.pamestoixima.gr/el/web/guest/retail-betting#r/543-543

Comment: Are you sure the contents are not subject to copyright?

Comment: No there is not problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pay attention to MartynA's concern that scraping this information does not violate the site's terms of service.

If data is loaded after the fact, you can use your browser's developer tools to get a better idea of what's going on.

I mostly use [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), but similar tools are available out of the box for [FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/son/docs/Tools), [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx), Edge, etc.

Look at the [Network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#network_panel) and reload your page. All of the network requests will be shown. Click on one to see details, including a preview. Look through these until you see a JSON request that contains the data you are looking for. In Chrome, you can right-click on the resource and open it in a separate tab, giving you its direct URL, which you can retrieve using Indy.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question. You should post another one.